# create a personalized confirmation message when I click on the Back button of the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5.2

create custom popup if I want to disconnect (back to the login page) or not, when i click on the Back button of the browser.

Comment: you can use this, but it is disappearing quickly:                                                    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $(".modal_Popup").show();
   }

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
      return 'Are you sure you want to disconnect?';
});
```

Comment: That will fire when the backbutton is clicked … and when the browser is closed, then a new URL is typed into the address bar, when any link is clicked, etc, etc.

Comment: you can use this, 
but it is disappearing quickly window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $(".modal_Popup").show();
   }